# At which level in Visual Studio 2010 do you get support for remote debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My company is looking to upgrade to VS2010 and one feature which we would really like to have is remote debugging. We currently run 2005 Standard Edition, which does not have this feature (but Team Suite does).

Looking at the VS2010 website it only says there is debugging (in general) across all versions. I can't find any information about whether remote debugging specifically is available across the whole range or if it only comes in the more expensive packages.

Does anyone have the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pro, Premium, and Ultimate has remote debugging. Express does not.

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx